# Understanding How to implement generics in java using keys and values

Tags: java

I am currently trying to understand how to implement this program. I understand how interfaces work. They are functions you must initialize each time you implement them. I understand that generics are functions made to perform the same function on more than one data type. But I'm currently stuck understanding how I'm supposed to finish the code below. How does the key and value generics work? If someone can help me understand how to implement one of the functions? Maybe the one for remove with a key I would appreciate it.

SimpleBoundedList.java

```
public class SimpleBoundedList<K extends Comparable<K>,V> implements List<K, V> {

    protected Object[] values;

    private int start = 0;
    private int nextEmpty = 0;

    /**
     * 
     */
    public SimpleBoundedList(int bound) {
        values = new Object[bound];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(K key, V value) {
        boolean modify = false;
        int nextIndex = nextEmpty;

        if (((nextEmpty + 1) % values.length) != start) {
            nextEmpty = (nextEmpty + 1) % values.length;
            modify = true;
        } else if (values[nextEmpty] == null) {
            modify = true;
        }

        if (modify)
            values[nextIndex] = new Entry<K,V>(key,value);

        return modify;
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(K key) {
            return null;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public V lookup(K key) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(int n) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return values.length;
    }

    @Override
    public V get(int n) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public V remove() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    private class Entry<K, V> {

        protected K key;
        protected V value;

        public Entry(K key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }

    }


}
```

List.java

```
public interface List<K extends Comparable<K>,V> {

    public abstract boolean add(K key,V value);

    public abstract V remove(K key);

    public abstract V remove(int n);

    public abstract V remove();

    public abstract V lookup(K key);

    public abstract int size();

    public abstract V get(int n);

}
```

Comment: Anyone's got any ideas?